# React Native: Unable to use SSL module

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native, ssl-certificate

I am attempting to add this SSL security module for android: `react-native-ssl-pinning`. I have successfully gone through the steps and have my certificate placed in src/main/assets.
https://github.com/MaxToyberman/react-native-ssl-pinning

Now I am using this module:

```
import {fetch} from 'react-native-ssl-pinning';

...

var url = "https:/my/aws/appsync/url";

fetch(url, {
    method: "POST" ,
    timeoutInterval: 4000, // milliseconds
    body: body,
    sslPinning: {
        certs: ["cert1","cert2"]
    },
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json; charset=utf-8", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", "e_platform": "mobile",
    }
})
.then(response => {
    console.log(`response received ${response}`)
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(`error: ${err}`)
})
```

I am getting the below error:

`ReferenceError: Can't find variable: body`

what is 'body' field in above? What do I have to put there?

**UPDATE:**

Actually I am making a function call to the AWS graphql endpoint.
So, in above code, I replaced the line

`body: body,`

with

`body: API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listFeedItems))`

Now, my error has changed to:
`TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Comment: `body` is the content you want to send to the endpoint?

Comment: @MaartenDev. Actually I am making a function call to the endpoint. I now replaced body with `API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listFeedItems))`. Now I am getting error `TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Comment: Before sending the data to the API endpoint, please check If your `API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listFeedItems))` is some valid data or not by `console.log` of same.